# Regex match folder and all subfolders

Tags: regex

I need to write a Regex for a backup exclusion filter to exclude a folder and all of it's subfolders.

I need to match the following

`folder1/statistics
folder1/statistics/*
folder2/statistics
folder2/statistics/*`

I came up with this Regex which matches the folder statistics, but not the subfolders of the statistics folder.

`[^/]+/statistics/`

How do I expand this expression to match all subfolders below the statistics folder?

Comment: Use [`^[^\/]+\/statistics(?:\/?[^\/]+)*\/?$`](https://regex101.com/r/lL4uE0/1)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use following regex:

```
/^[^\/]+\/statistics\/?(?:[^\/]+\/?)*$/gm
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gO4eS8/3).

Explanation:

```
/
  ^           # matches start of line
 [^\/]+       # matches any character other than / one or more times
 \/statistics # matches /statistics
 \/?          # optionally matches /
 (?:          # non-capturing group
   [^\/]+     # matches any character other than / one or more times
   \/?        # optionally matches /
 )*           # zero or more times
 $            # matches end of line
/
g             # global flag - matches all
m             # multi-line flag - ^ and $ matches start and end of lines
```

Comment: It will also match `folder1/statistics1234` and it should not. A possible fix is to add a word boundary: `(^[^\/]+\/statistics\b(?:\/?[^\/]+)*\/?$)` https://regex101.com/r/lL4uE0/20.

Answer (score 7):

What about using | (or):

```
'.*/statistics($|/.*)'
```

Explanation:

```
.*             # any length string
/statistics    # statistics directory
($|/.*)        # end of string or any string starting with /
```

It does the job and is not hard to comprehend. Tested with python re module.