# Regex for all folders under one folder with a specific name

Tags: regex

I have a EFS will thousands of folders, I need a regex that can find a folder called "NewFile" and select all the xml files in it which is in any of directory listed from the root directory.

i.e.

selects:

C:\dir1\something\something2\NewFile\some.xml

C:\dir1\something\NewFile\some2.xml

C:\dir1\NewFile\some3.xml

ignores:

C:\dir1\something\something.xml

I did some research and found this question

[Regex match folder and all subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691809/regex-match-folder-and-all-subfolders)

But it was matching the folder name at the same level

Comment: Try `NewFile\\.*?\.xml` or `^(.*?(?:\\|^))NewFile\\(.*?)([^\\]*\.xml)$`

Comment: What language/environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to match pathnames that contain NewFile followed by an XML file:

```
/NewFile\\.*\.xml$/
```

Comment: EFS is on a windows machine. Java lib will execute the expression

Comment: Your test string uses `/` as a separator but your sample in the question used `\\`. See https://regex101.com/r/y1GHWg/2

Comment: Yup youre, I used the wrong slash in the regex101.  Looks fine to me. thanks

Comment: Good job, keep it up ! +1