# MyPy configuration - exclude subdirectories with matching name

Tags: python, mypy

I'm trying to exclude some directories at my `mypy.ini` file by using the `exclude` option.
The directories I'm trying to exclude match the format `*/test/*`, being `*` any amount of subdirectories (can be none).

For example, I can have the following structure, where **I'd like to exclude all folders named `test` regardless of where they are**:

```
src/
├── foo/
│   ├── test/
│   |   └── a_test
│   └── foofile
└── test/
    └── another_test
```

I thought that I could use regular expressions in order to match these folders, and I tried [some regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691809/regex-match-folder-and-all-subfolders) but none seem to work.

Can I get some help with this? Essentially, what I want to have is something like this:

```
[mypy]
exclude = "<anything>/test/"
```

Where I don't know how to specify the <anything> part.

Comment: Additionally, a `pyproject.toml` solution would be appreciated.

Comment: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#confval-exclude ?

Comment: @DeepSpace that example only features files. I tried it with folders, but I haven't been able to make it work. (Just to clarify it, I know nothing about regex, so I might have done something wrong)

Comment: The very first line says "A regular expression that matches file names, directory names and paths which mypy should ignore"

Comment: @DeepSpace sorry, I forgot to specify that I'm trying the --exclude option with no success, not that I didn't know which option to use.

Comment: Did you try `exclude=test`? you don't need a regex at all

Comment: @DeepSpace thanks, that worked. Problem was that I was using quotes because I was previously using a pyproject.toml file. Could you write it as an answer so I can mark this as resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to exclude *all* dirs called `test`, you don't need a regex at all:

```ini
[mypy]
exclude=test
```